# printf symbol name and value

Tags: eval, string-formatting, racket

Suppose somewhere I have defined several symbols:

```
#lang racket
(define foo 123)
(define bar '("1" "2" "3"))
```

I need a way to produce a string like `"foo = 123"` or `"bar = '("1" "2" "3")"`. I wrote a function for that:

```
(define (f2 sy)
  (format "~a = ~s" sy (eval sy)))
```

This function works in the interpretator window pretty well.

```
> (f2 'foo)
"foo = 123"
> (f2 'bar)
"bar = (\"1\" \"2\" \"3\")"
```

That is quite satisfactory for me. However, when I use it in the code, I get

```
foo: unbound identifier;
 also, no #%top syntax transformer is bound in: foo
```

I have a feeling that I am doing something wrong. Can you please suggest the right way to solve my problem?

P.S.: I am using `DrRacket, version 5.3.1`

Comment: Asumu Takikawa suggested two solutions: either write a macro, but then it cannot be `map`-ed on a list, or refer to some namespace, like this:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `eval` should really only be used as a last resort in Racket. It makes your program less efficient and harder to understand. The right way to do this is probably to write a macro such as the following:

```
(define-syntax-rule (f2 sy)
  (format "~a = ~s" (quote sy) sy))

(define foo 2)
(f2 foo)
```

This macro just substitutes the name of the variable you want to lookup into the format expression in the body. The `quote` turns the variable name into a symbol you can print. This macro doesn't work as a procedure, because `(f2 foo)` would deference `foo` before you can `quote` and print its name.

---

Note: the reason why your `eval` doesn't work as expected is because `eval` always evaluates with respect to a namespace, which dictates what is in scope. The default namespace within a module has nothing in it, so `eval` can't see `foo` or anything else. You can read more about namespaces in the [Guide](http://pre.racket-lang.org/docs/html/guide/eval.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But is it possible to `map` this macro to a list of symbols? In my problem I need to call my `f2` many times.

Comment: No, you can't `map` a macro since it's not a procedure. You can write a version of `f2` that works on multiple identifiers at once though.

Comment: Could you please give some hints or references how to do that?

Comment: Given the above definition of `f2`, you can write something like `(define-syntax-rule (f2* sy ...) (list (f2 sy) ...))`. The `...` lets you define a macro that matches on an arbitrary number of things at once and substitute them into the body. You may want to read the [Guide](http://pre.racket-lang.org/docs/html/guide/pattern-macros.html) entry on macros or maybe Greg Hendershott's [Fear of Macros](http://www.greghendershott.com/fear-of-macros/) tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, also inspired by Asumu Takikawa uses the trick described in the guide:

```
(define-namespace-anchor a)
(define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace a))

(define (f2 sy)
  (format "~a = ~s" sy (eval sy ns)))
```

On the contrast to the solution with macros, this function can be mapped.